# Persistent Mac terminal syntax error after Homebrew and Ruby installation

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, terminal, homebrew

Steps at https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite to install Homebrew and Ruby onto Mac OS X 10.10.5 includes running these lines in terminal:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build  

echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bash_profile
```

Both lines now run successfully, but this error message is appearing each time terminal is opened (name replaced with “x”):

```
-bash: /Users/x/.bash_profile: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: /Users/x/.bash_profile: line 12: `export PATH="/Users/x/anaconda/bin:$PATH"if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi'
```

Searching on the error and variations of “terminal opens with bash error” have not turned up a way to remove the error message.

Answer (score 1):

When you added the code to initialize rbenv to your `.bash_profile`, it was erronously appended to the last line in that file instead of being added to a new line.

To fix this, edit the file ~/.bash_profile (e.g. by running `nano ~/.bash_profile`) and add a new line so that the end of the line reads as follows:

```
export PATH="/Users/x/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

You can then save the file and exit the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect! That solved it, thank you so much for the thorough description.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217589) it.